Missing Norwegian Language in Google Text-To-Speech
From the following list: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices, I'm able to find Norwegian language in supported languages, though, I'm not able to find it in the actual Cloud Text-To-Speech API. Can anyone help me? My best guess is that they forgot to enter it.

Then contact Google to get them to enter it - not something we have any control over.
